# How to get local path of a url

Tags: php, path

`$url = 'http://www.site.com/files/file.jpg';`

How can I get the local path, like

`C:\htdocs\site/files/file.jpg`

?

Comment: You need to know the path for the webserver document root

Comment: Have you checked at $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking abut getting the local path of a document on a remote server that you don't have access to (other than HTTP), you can't.

If you're trying to get the path of a document on your server, you need an absolute or relative path to the root of the site and then you can derive the full path from there.

Answer (score 3):

You first get the document root of your site with

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

And then you append the relative path to your resource
Ex:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/relative/path/to/files/file.jpg';
```

Comment: In your solution you are supposed to know the local path name of the file in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://blabla.info/somepath/somefile.php

```
echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];
```

results in [/var/www/htdocs/blabla.info/somepath/somefile.php]

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

something as simple as this :

```
<?php echo __FILE__; ?>
```

Comment: OK, but if you are calling __FILE__ from an include(d) file you would get the included file location and not the local URL file location as it is asked